# Appengine/ComputeEngine Memory Issue?

Tags: google-app-engine, memory, google-compute-engine

I suspect this is a straightforward memory leak issue (python27 process has a memory leak with appengine libraries running on the Managed VMs GCE containers), but I'm confused a few things about the data I was collecting during the OOM issues.

After running fine for most of a day, my "vmstat 1" suddenly changed drastically:

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 0  0      0  70116   7612  41240    0    0     0    64  231  645  3  2 95  0
 0  0      0  70148   7612  41240    0    0     0     0  164  459  2  2 96  0
 1  0      0  70200   7612  41240    0    0     0     0  209  712  2  1 97  0
 1  0      0  65432   7612  41344    0    0   100     0  602  820 48  5 47  1
 1  3      0  69840   5644  29620    0    0  1284     0  812  797 33  6 34 27
 0  1      0  69068   5896  30216    0    0   852    68  362 1052  6  1  0 93
 0  1      0  68340   6160  30536    0    0   556     0  547 1355  4  2  0 94
 0  2      0  67928   6564  30972    0    0   872     0  793 2173  9  5  0 86
 0  1      0  63988   6888  34416    0    0  3776     0  716 1940  3  3  0 94
 3  0      0  63696   7104  34608    0    0   376     0  353 1006  4  4 34 58
 0  0      0  63548   7112  34948    0    0   332    48  379  916 13  1 84  2
 0  0      0  63636   7116  34948    0    0     4     0  184  637  0  1 99  0
 0  0      0  63660   7116  34948    0    0     0     0  203  556  0  3 97  0
 0  1      0  76100   3648  26128    0    0   460     0  409 1142  7  4 85  4
 0  3      0  73452    948  15940    0    0  4144    80 1041 1126 53  6 10 31
 0  6      0  73828     84  11424    0    0 32924    80 1135 1732 11  4  0 85
 0  6      0  72684     64  12324    0    0 52168     4 1519 2397  6  3  0 91
 0 11      0  67340     52  12328    0    0 78072    16 1388 2974  2  9  0 89
 1 10      0  65992    336  13412    0    0 79796     0 1297 2973  0  9  0 91
 0 15      0  69000     48  10396    0    0 78344     0 1203 2739  2  7  0 91
 0 15      0  67168     52  11460    0    0 86864     0 1244 3003  0  6  0 94
 1 15      0  71268     52   7836    0    0 82552     4 1497 3269  0  7  0 93
```

In particular, my memory cache and buff dropped, and the io bytes-in surged, and it stayed like this for ~10 minutes afterwards before the machine died and was rebooted by Google Compute Engine. I assume the "bi" represents bytes-in from disk, but I'm curious why swpd showed 0 for this instance, if there was swapping? And why is memory "free" stat still unaffected if things are reaching a swapping point?

Second at the time of the final crash, my top showed:

```
Top - 15:06:20 up 1 day, 13:23,  2 users,  load average: 13.88, 11.22, 9.30
Tasks:  92 total,   3 running,  89 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.8 us,  8.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id, 90.9 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.4 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   1745136 total,  1684032 used,    61104 free,      648 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free,    12236 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND  
   23 root      20   0     0    0    0 R  12.6  0.0   2:11.61 kswapd0                                              
   10 root      rt   0     0    0    0 S   2.5  0.0   0:52.92 watchdog/0                                           
 2315 root      20   0  192m  17m    0 S   2.1  1.0  47:58.74 kubelet                                              
 2993 root      20   0 6116m 1.2g    0 S   0.9 70.2 318:41.51 python2.7                                            
 6644 root      20   0 55452  12m    0 S   0.9  0.7   0:00.81 python                                               
 2011 root      20   0  761m 9924    0 S   0.7  0.6  12:23.44 docker                                               
 6624 root      20   0  4176  132    0 D   0.5  0.0   0:00.24 du                                                   
  140 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0.4  0.0   0:08.64 kworker/0:1H                                         
 2472 root      20   0 39680 5616  296 D   0.4  0.3   0:27.43 python                                               
    1 root      20   0 10656  132    0 S   0.2  0.0   0:02.61 init                                                 
    3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.2  0.0   2:02.17 ksoftirqd/0                                          
   22 root      20   0     0    0    0 R   0.2  0.0   0:24.61 kworker/0:1                                          
 1834 root      20   0 53116  756    0 S   0.2  0.0   0:01.79 rsyslogd                                             
 1859 root      20   0 52468 9624    0 D   0.2  0.6   0:29.36 supervisord                                          
 2559 root      20   0  349m 172m    0 S   0.2 10.1  25:56.31 ruby
```

Again, I see the python27 process has claimed to 70% (which when combined with the 10% from Ruby, puts me into dangerous territory). Buy why is kswapd going crazy with my 10% CPU when the above vmstat shows 0?

Should I just not trust vmstat's swapd?

Comment: Did you try update python? What GAE lib are you using?

Comment: I'm unclear what your questions are asking. I'm running a Docker image based on gcr.io/google_appengine/python-compat. I wasn't aware I even had an option for updating python...so don't believe I've tried that. As far as "GAE lib", I'm unclear what exactly the "GAE lib" is. I'm pushing from an updated glcoud sdk 0.9.89 with app-engine-python 1.9.28, using the above Docker image for my runtime deployment. Does that answer your question, or were you asking something else?

Comment: GAE libs are the Google App Engine libraries you mentioned above. The latest version of Google App Engine SDK is 1.9.30 and Google Cloud SDK is 90.0.0. You can also update your Python to 2.7.11 to see if the issue is related to a specific version that you're using right now.

Comment: I can try updating libraries, potentially as a fix to the memory leaks. But I am using Python NDB, which unfortunately has known unfixed memory leaks with clear repro examples (and bugs filed), which I suspect are the cause of my leaks here. But I was more curious how to interpret vmstat: why are free bytes remaining high and swpd remaining zero, even as I run out of memory (buffer drops to zero, bi bytes-in goes through the roof, and the process/machine goes unresponsive before ending rebooted).

Comment: Yes, there is a long thread about Python NDB memory leaks issue on this public issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9610

Comment: Right, I am one of the contributors on that URL thread debugging and proposing patch fixes (some that went ignored by NDB owners, and regardless are still insufficient in fixing all NDB memory leaks). Appreciate your help here, but my stackoverflow question was more about vmstat interpretation and the behavior of the GCE instance under memory load.